# Talend : "main link" does not work before a SubJob for retrieving value from it

Tags: etl, talend

I have a problem with my Talend job.
My objective is to start from a list of persons (extracted from a database) and for each line in the list check if the ID already exists in the Active Directory.

The subjob (cherche_doublon_id) whose check if the ID already exists work fine. The job should return a result "idUnique" if the ID does not exist, and "idDoublon" in the othe case.
This subjob use the ID which is transmitted by the parent as context parameter.

My problem seems to be the connection "main" whose enter in my child job. If I put a "OnComponentOk", the subjob work well, but only one time on the latest element of my list. With the "main" connection, I wanted to execute the subjob for each line in my list, but I can not retrieve the result on the job.

Here you can find my job and the settings of the components:
[image: my job and the settings of the components]

If I do with a "OnComponentOk" link before the subjob, I can retrieve without any dificulties. 
See the corresponding screenshot:
[image: See the corresponding screenshot]

But in my case, "OnComponentOk" cannot be viable because I want to do my stuff for each line in the liste.

Comment: Kindly provide the screenshot of tJavaRow_2 schema

Comment: Here you can find the schema : http://www.cjoint.com/c/FKjhUhczIBe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem by changing the structure of my jobs.
In my initial question, I tried to retrieve te result of my first job "cherche_doublon", and I wanted to filter on this result.

Now I decided to work in cascade mode.

That means I have my first job :
liste_titulaires → affect_global → cherche_doublon

And inside my cherche_doublon, I do my stuff, and at the end in fonction of my result I do the one or the other job :
[Here the image of the subjob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqDrM.png)

I have other sub sub jobs.
The good point is that in my main job, I iterate on each element of my list and all the treatment inside my subjobs is done. I use context parameters to transmitt the information I nead.

All is working fine now.
Thank you for your help.

Damien.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear in how your job looks like. You provided much information in pictured, but no complete pictures of your main and subjobs.

So, I am trying to guess a few things:

- tJava is not working row-based so this might be a reason for the problem if you also use it in your job
- onComponentOk lets the first part run through completely, explaining the behaviour that only the last entry is being provided. So this splits jobs into several separated steps
- The way to check for missing or already existing entries looks overly complicated in general. Why a subjob?

I would go with a job layout like this:

```
Liste titulaires --row--> tMap --rowFound-->doStuff
            AD --lookup--/    \--rowNotFound-->doOtherStuff
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I did not put a screenshot of my subjob because it works fine. It checks the id of the user (context.glb_individu_id) with a tMap if this ID already exists in the AD. If it exists, I set a tBufferOutput with 1 line to "idDoublon".
I read this value at the end of the subjob.

I did this function in a separated job because I use this same function in an other job. It is better for me to just call my subjob than write again the same code.

Now, I think I will use a raw file to write my result as a global variable. It is not the cleaner way, but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tFlowToIterate between tHashInput and tRunJob. It will create a global variable for each column of your tHashInput. You can then link tFlowToIterate to tRunJob with iterate link, and configure tRunjob by passing the tFlowToIterate.Id field to your variable glb_individu_id.